# Send logfile output to console

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a powershell script that runs an exe to install the dotnet framework.  This exe does not log to the console but can log to a file.  I need to see the log in our deployment tool which will display the console.

I run the exe like this:

```
$process = Start-Process  "$exe" "/q /norestart /log $logFile" -passthru
```

Then I send the content of the logfile to the console like this:

```
get-content $logFile -tail 5 -wait
```

This works, but the script never ends.  The -wait keeps waiting on new lines even after everything is done.

I've tried running get-content as a job, using Start-Job but then I can't get output to the console (as it's running).

Any ideas?

Comment: `Start-Job` is the right approach, you just need to call `Receive-Job` in a loop (in which you monitor if the installer has exited) in order to see the log lines as they're being added.

Comment: If your problem isn't solved yet, please provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is wait for the installer to finish. Then you can read the log file contents into the console after the process exits. Unfortunately, `Get-Content` has no idea when the file you are reading is done being written to, and requires the user to terminate the read when `-Wait` is used.

If you really want to go through the extra effort, you can use `Start-Job` or `Start-ThreadJob` as outlined in @mklement0's answer to run either the installer or the logger in the background.

Comment: I tried that but it takes a long time and people think it's hung an restart.  That's why I want the log output to display as it goes.

Comment: What you want isn't impossible but requires lower level coding as you can't use `Get-Content` in this way. Might be more prudent just to `Write-Output "Installing .NET framwork. Please do not close this window or restart the computer"`, and remember to write a completion message when finished.

Answer (score 0):

**Unless the target file gets *deleted*, `Get-Content -Wait` runs *indefinitely*** (requires pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to terminate).

**However, you *can* use a *background [thread] job* to monitor the log file, while using a foreground loop to collect and display the job's output periodically, via `Receive-Job`, and exit that loop once the installer process has exited**:

The following self-contained code demonstrates the technique:

Note: I'm using the child-process-based `Start-Job` to create the background job, but if the 
[`Start-ThreadJob` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) is available to you, you can use it as a more lightweight, thread-based alternative (`Start-ThreadJob` ships with PowerShell *Core*; in Windows PowerShell you can install it with `Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser`, for instance).

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Write-Verbose 'Starting installer process in the background.'
$ps = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -PassThru pwsh '-noprofile', '-command', 
  '$null > $HOME/test.log; 1..20 | % { $_ >> $HOME/test.log; Start-Sleep 1 }'

Write-Verbose 'Starting log-file monitoring job.'
# If Start-ThreadJob is available to you, you can use it instead of Start-Job here.
$jb = Start-Job { 
  while (-not (Test-Path $HOME/test.log)) { Start-Sleep 1 }
  Get-Content $HOME/test.log -Last 5 -Wait 
}

Write-Verbose 'Receiving job output while waiting for the installer process to exit...'
while (-not $ps.HasExited) {
  Receive-Job $jb
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

Write-Verbose 'Installer process has exited, removing job.'
Remove-Job $jb -Force

# Remove the sample log file.
Remove-Item $HOME/test.log
```

**Caveat**: Unfortunately, `Start-ThreadJob` and `Start-Job` currently have their own idea what the current location (working directory) is, so it's best to use *full paths*; this [inconsistency will be fixed, in v7.0 at the earliest](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10673#issuecomment-540229636).

The above yields:

```
VERBOSE: Starting installer process in the background.
VERBOSE: Starting log-file monitoring job.
VERBOSE: Receiving job output while waiting for the installer process to exit...
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
VERBOSE: Installer process has exited, removing job.
```